# Como setar chave e valor de um objeto criando uma instância e colocar os valores no map?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Eu só sei fazer o hashmap de uma forma que é criando uma instância no método put para fazer inserção de valores.

Segue a forma que sei fazer:

```
import java.util.Map;

public class Teste {

public static void main(String[] args){

//Exemplo com utilização de hashmap

    Map<Pessoa, Pessoa> example = new HashMap<Pessoa, Pessoa>();



    example.put(new Pessoa(12), new Pessoa("Aline"));
    example.put(new Pessoa(13), new Pessoa("Carla"));

    int key = 2;

    if(example.containsKey(key)){
        System.out.println("Valor é:" + key + " = " + example.get(key));

    }else{
        System.out.println("Não existe!");
    }
  }
}
```

Mas não consegui fazer dessa forma como faz isso? exemplo:

```
import java.util.Map;

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args){



    //Exemplo com utilização de hashmap

        Map<Pessoa, Pessoa> example = new HashMap<Pessoa, Pessoa>();

        Pessoa pessoa;

        pessoa = new Pessoa();
        pessoa.setId(40);
        pessoa.setNome("Aline");

        example.put(pessoa.getId(), pessoa.getNome());

        int key = 2;

        if(example.containsKey(key)){
            System.out.println("Valor é:" + key + " = " + example.get(key));

        }else{
            System.out.println("Não existe!");
        }
    }




Class Pessoa:

package ibm;

public class Pessoa {
private Integer id;
private String nome;

Pessoa(Integer num){
 this.id    = num;
}

Pessoa(String nome){
    this.nome = nome;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
```

}

Comment: Se nome é string e id é int, porque você não declarou ` HashMap<String, Integer>()` ao inves de usar Pessoa? Não está claro o que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: Quando vc cria um new class vc esta alocando um ponteiro para os dados, talvez vc esteja querendo fazer um map<int, Pessoa>. Realmente não ficou muito claro a pergunta

Comment: Eu só quero fazer a implementação de uma forma que não precise criar instancia. eu quero pegar valores já definidos em uma objeto e inserir.

Answer (score 5):

Os tipos da chave e do valor do seu Map não batem com o que você está tentando inserir nele.

O Map é um tipo de coleção que guarda chaves e valores, com o objetivo de você localizar um valor através de sua chave. No caso você quer que a chave seja um inteiro (id) e o valor seja o nome da pessoa (String). Então seu Map deve refletir isso. Em outras palavras...

Esta linha:

```
Map<Pessoa, Pessoa> example = new HashMap<Pessoa, Pessoa>();
```

deveria ser trocada por:

```
Map<Integer, String> example = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

ou melhor ainda, por:

```
Map<Integer, String> example = new HashMap<>();
```

---

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:** Pensando melhor, talvez você queira fazer um pouco diferente e localizar uma Pessoa através do seu id. Nesse caso você deve declarar o seu Map assim:

```
Map<Integer, Pessoa> example = new HashMap<>();
```

e alterar seu `put()` assim:

```
example.put(pessoa.getId(), pessoa);
```

Feito isso, você poderá ver qual é o nome da pessoa assim:

```
Pessoa pessoa = example.get(id);
System.out.println("Nome: " + pessoa.getNome());
```

Comment: mas na Pessoa estou inserindo um id.

Comment: E o que tem isso a ver com o que eu falei? O seu `put(pessoa.getId(), pessoa.getNome())` está correto, o que você precisa trocar é a declaração do seu map de `Map<Pessoa, Pessoa>` para `Map<Integer, String>`. Porque `getId()` retorna um inteiro e `getNome()` retorna uma String, seu map deve ser compatível com isso, deve guardar inteiros apontando para Strings.

Comment: Vou tentar isso

Comment: Bem, vou tentar explicar, o id é um Integer e o nome é uma String logo o que esta descrito ali é vc irá criar uma mapa de chave Integer (id) que ira guardar Strings (nome), ou seja, Map<int, String>()

Comment: @user3010128 Correto, a única ressalva é que no lugar de `int` que é um tipo primitivo tem que ser a classe `Integer`, mas acho que você já sabe disso.

Comment: Pensando melhor, talvez você queira fazer um pouco diferente e localizar uma Pessoa através do seu id. Atualizei a resposta explicando como fazer.